# Babel multiple language and chapter labels

Tags: pdftex, babel, labels

I am writing a Ph.D. thesis that is written in english but should contain one chapter in french. I tried to add multiple language support, using:

```
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
```

But if I do that, at the first label after the first chapter I have strange errors:

```
\chapter{Test}
\label{chap:test}
This is a test chapter.
```

If I remove the `\label{chap:test}` it works without any problem.
Someone knows where could the problem be and how to solve it?

The first error is:

```
[3] (./Tesi.aux (./Chapters/FrechR.aux
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \mathrel 
l.8 ...narycolon }test}{{1}{2}{Test}{chapter.1}{}}
```

While I the preamble is

```
% Declare that this style file requires at least LaTeX version 2e.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

%\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx} %serve create a pdf-a

% Provide the name of your page, the date it was last updated, and a comment about what it's used for
\ProvidesPackage{Preamble}[2019/03/29 Stefano thesis preamble]

\usepackage[french, english]{babel} %linguistic support (stefano)
% General Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % For input encoding and stressed characters
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} % for right csquotes detection
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=25mm,bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry} % For correct positionning on a A4 paper sheet
\usepackage{graphicx} % For \includegraphics[scale=•]{•}
\usepackage{url} %for correct visualization of urls

% Font Packages
% \usepackage{lmodern} % For Latin Modern !!! Way too thin !!!
% \usepackage{textcomp} %companion fonts, cross and tics mainly (stefano)
\usepackage{libertine} % For Linux Libertine
\usepackage{amsthm} %for writing theorems has to be before newtxmath
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} % For Linux Libertine matching math font
%\usepackage{libertinust1math} % For better Linux Libertine maths | needs to be installed though but should be pretty nice
\usepackage{commath}

% Other fonts I tried
%\usepackage{fouriernc} % URW Schoolbook L (Val's maths, too crazy)
%\usepackage{tgschola} % Enhanced URW Schoolbook L (replaces text glyphs)
%\usepackage{stix} % For Stix font along with its maths (DID NOT WORK)
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % For TX fonts along with maths (newtxtext DID NOT WORK)

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % For nice hyphenation of words with accented characters mostly

% \usepackage{listings} %for listings of codes
% \lstloadlanguages{C, bash}
% \lstnewenvironment{lstC}[1][]
% {\lstset{language=C,numbers=left,breaklines=true,
%     basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,#1}}{}
% \lstnewenvironment{lstbash}[1][]
% {\lstset{language=bash,numbers=left,breaklines=true,
%     basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,#1}}{}

% \makeatletter
% \lst@Key{matchrangestart}{f}{\lstKV@SetIf{#1}\lst@ifmatchrangestart}
% \def\lst@SkipToFirst{%
%   \lst@ifmatchrangestart\c@lstnumber=\numexpr-1+\lst@firstline\fi
%   \ifnum \lst@lineno<\lst@firstline
%   \def\lst@next{\lst@BeginDropInput\lst@Pmode
%     \lst@Let{13}\lst@MSkipToFirst
%     \lst@Let{10}\lst@MSkipToFirst}%
%   \expandafter\lst@next
%   \else
%   \expandafter\lst@BOLGobble
%   \fi}
% \makeatother

% Maths Packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{amsfonts} loaded by the following
\usepackage{amssymb} % For more maths symbols. It loads amsfonts package.
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon} %normally used in europe
\renewcommand{\theta}{\vartheta} %normally used in europe
\renewcommand{\rho}{\varrho} %normally used in europe
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi} %normally used in europe


\newcommand\bmmax{2} % Just to help bm dealing with over 16 maths alphabets

\usepackage{bm} % For bold maths symbols
\usepackage{dsfont} % For a nice double-sided capital 1 with \mathds{1}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % For nice script like capital letters with \mathsf{L}

% Headers, footers configuration
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For nice headers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont \slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\fontsize{10}{12} \selectfont \slshape \rightmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\usepackage{emptypage} % To clear empty pages with \thispagestyle{empty}

% Links
%\usepackage[pagebackref=true, colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0},
\usepackage[pagebackref=false, colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0},
pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksdepth=3,pdfencoding=auto, psdextra]{hyperref} % For clickable links through
                                                  % the doc and backreferencing
                                                  % in the biblio
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\gd{antibunching}}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=[rgb]{0.47,0.04,0.76},
  linkcolor=[rgb]{0.00,0.45,0.81},bookmarksnumbered} % Setting some nice colors

% %Tuning the backreferencing
% \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
% \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{({\footnotesize%
%     \ifcase #1 Not cited.%
%     \or Cited on page~#2.%
%     \else Cited on pages #2.%
%     \fi%
%   })}

% Miscellanous Packages
\usepackage{bookmark} % For advanced PDF bookmarks management
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption} % For side-by-side figures which I didn't use
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig} % For side-by-side figures, caption=false
                                % tell to not affect the caption. To be
                                % evaluated.
\usepackage{cprotect} % for protected captions
%\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{#1#2#3\hspace{0.25\linewidth}\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.3pt}}
%\captionsetup[figure]{format=myformat} %%add a line after each figure caption


% \usepackage{wrapfig} used to wrap text around figures
% \usepackage{rotating} % girare le figure

\usepackage[exponent-product=\cdot]{siunitx} % For nice scientific notation,
%nicely displayed units,
                     % check the doc
\usepackage{booktabs} % For really nice tabs
%\usepackage{todonotes} % For to-do list - Did not use it
%\usepackage{multicol} % For multicolumn environment - Did not use it
\usepackage[tight]{minitoc} % For tables of content by chapters / recommend the
                            % tight option
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} % For appendices management
\usepackage[above,below]{placeins} % To avoid floats (figures) passing anythin
%with \FloatBarrier
\usepackage{floatrow}

%%to add boxes around figures

%end to add boxes around figures

% Configure the depth of sections, table of content and minitoc
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} % I like to have numbering down to subsubections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % You want to stop the main toc at subsections, that's more than enough
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{3} % You want them all in minitocs


% Paths for figures and logos
\graphicspath{{Immagini/}}

%for quantum states
%\usepackage{braket}

% Some life saving macro to speed up writing and give you agility

% \def\({\left(} % super useful
% \def\){\right)} % super useful
% \def\[{\left[}
% \def\]{\right]}
% \def\bdiv{\;\big/\;} % Oh yeah ! Big div baby ! Big div !
% \def\+{\dagger} % Cause ^\+ is much better than ^{\dagger}
% \def\8{\infty}


%------------ other random commands I define ---------------%


%\newcommand{\ba}[1]{\begin{array}{#1}}
%\newcommand{\ea}{\end{array}}

%\newcommand{\lr}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
%\newcommand{\ddd}{\mathrm{d}}

% Here's the Greek ! Always business !
% \def\a{\alpha}
% \def\b{\beta}
% \def\g{\gamma}
% \def\G{\Gamma}
% \def\d{\delta}
% \def\D{\Delta}
% \def\eps{\varepsilon}
% \def\e0{\epsilon_0}
% \def\ka{\kappa}
% \def\la{\lambda}
% \def\m{\mu}
% \def\n{\nu}
% \def\p{\psi}
% \def\P{\Psi}
% \def\po{\mathcal{P}} % For optical powers
% \def\s{\sigma}
% \def\t{\tau}
% \def\tt{\theta}
% \def\vtt{\theta_{pol}} % I initialy used \varepsilon ...  whatever
% \def\v{\nu}
% \def\w{\omega}
% \def\W{\Omega}
% \def\l"{\lq\lq} % In English, they look like that, period
% \def\r"{\rq\rq}
% \def\E{\hat{\textbf{E}}} % For the electric field
% \def\fE{\mathscr{E}^{(1)}} % For the field constant
% \def\rp{\bm{r}} % For the position vector
% \def\k{\textbf{k}} % Momentum vector

% %quadrature vectors
% \def\q{\textbf{q}}
% \def\p{\textbf{p}}

% \def\pd{\partial} % For partial derivation
% \def\ldots{...} % I redefined them, originals are too spaced
% \def\twith{\quad \text{with} \quad} % I like to put that in equations
% \def\twhere{\quad \text{where} \quad} % Same
% \def\tand{\quad \text{and} \quad} % same


% % Functions
% \DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\ch}{ch}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\sh}{sh}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\tnh}{th}
% \DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}
%\let\Re\undefined %cambio il comando per la parte reale, che non mi piace
%\DeclareMathOperator{\Re}{Re}
\newcommand{\NA}{\mathrm{NA}}
\newcommand{\defeq}{\stackrel{\text{\tiny def}}{=}}
% \newcommand{\ud}{\,\mathrm{d}} % For upright d in the integrals
% \newcommand{\matrixel}[3]{\ensuremath{\left\langle #1 \vphantom{#2#3} \right| #2 \left| #3 \vphantom{#1#2} \right\rangle}} % For Dirac notation matrix element
% \newcommand{\analE}[1]{\E^{(#1)}} % It's the analytic field, not what you're thinking !

% For Chapter Quotes
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}%
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}%
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax%
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}

% For the biblio's name
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

%%---- quantum circuit package ------%
%\input{Qcircuit}
%%--- avarage ---%
\newcommand{\avr}[1]{\left<#1\right>}

%---- basic Dirac notation ----%
\newcommand{\Bra}[2][]{\left<#2\right|_{#1}}
\newcommand{\Ket}[2][]{\left|#2\right>_{\hspace{-0.1em}#1}}

% ---- compound Dirac notation ----%
%\newcommand{\ketbra}[3][]{\mathinner{\lvert#2\rangle\langle #3\rvert}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\Ketbra}[3][]{\left|#2\middle> _{#1} \middle<#3\right|}
\newcommand{\proj}[2][]{\ketbra[#1]{#2}{#2}}
\newcommand{\Proj}[2][]{\Ketbra[#1]{#2}{#2}}


\newcommand{\Bracket}[4][]{_{#1}\mathinner{\langle #2 \lvert #3 \rangle}_{#4}}

%%------------ other random commands I define ---------------%

%\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
%\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}


% \newcommand\restr[2]{{% we make the whole thing an ordinary symbol
%   \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace % automatically resize the bar with \right
%   #1 % the function
%   \vphantom{\big|} % pretend it's a little taller at normal size
%   \right|_{#2} % this is the delimiter
%   }}

%\newcommand{\bs}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}


% \renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}
% \renewcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}

%%---- commands from stefano ----%%


% % useful when using listings package
% \newcommand{\inclC}[3][]{
%   \lstinputlisting[linerange={#2}, breaklines=true, matchrangestart=t,
%   numbers=left, language=C, basicstyle=\small\ttfamily , #1]{#3} }
% \newcommand{\inclMat}[3][]{
%   \lstinputlisting[linerange={#2}, breaklines=true, matchrangestart=t,
%   numbers=left, language=Matlab, basicstyle=\small\ttfamily , #1]{#3} }

\newcommand*{\fig}[1]{figure~\ref{fig:#1}}
\newcommand*{\eng}[1]{\textit{#1}}

%\newcommand*{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial#1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand*{\ppd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2^2}}
\newcommand{\den}{1+\dfrac{R_5}{R_3}+\dfrac{R_5}{R_4}}

%\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}
\newcommand{\tonda}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\of}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\quadra}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\graffa}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\D}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<#1\right|}
\newcommand{\braket}[3]{\left<#1\middle|#2\middle|#3\right>}
\newcommand{\mean}[1]{\left<#1\right>}

\newcommand{\Erel}[1]{ \\
  tonda{\dfrac{\Delta #1}{#1}}^2}
\newcommand{\down}[1]{\frac{1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ddown}[1]{\dfrac{1}{#1}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Variance}{\widehat{Var}}
\newcommand{\Var}[1]{\Variance\of{#1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}


\newcommand{\Sch}{Schr\"odinger}

% \newcommand{\aaa}[1]{\hat{a}_{#1}}
% \newcommand{\aad}[1]{\hat{a}_{#1}^{\dag}}
% \newcommand{\bbb}[1]{\hat{b}_{#1}}
% \newcommand{\bbd}[1]{\hat{b}_{#1}^{\dag}}
% \newcommand{\kort}{k_{\perp}}
% \newcommand{\kortv}{\vec{k}_{\perp}}
\newcommand{\Matlab}{Matlab}
% \newcommand{\slf}{\mathscr{E}}
% \newcommand{\slft}{\tilde{\mathscr{E}}}
% \newcommand{\Def}{\overset{\mathit{def}}{=}}
\newcommand{\Rasp}{Raspberry-Pi}
\newcommand{\Raspbian}{``Raspbian''}
% \newcommand{\usbtmc}{\textsc{usbtmc}}
\newcommand{\Python}{\textit{Python}}
\newcommand{\Bash}{\textit{Bash}}
\newcommand{\gd}{$\textrm{g}^{(2)}$}
\newcommand{\gdt}{$\textrm{g}^{(2)}\of{\tau}$}
\newcommand{\gdz}{$\textrm{g}^{(2)}\of{0}$}

\newcommand{\credit}[1]{\textit{credits: #1}.}
\newcommand{\ccredit}[1]{\textit{(credits: \textcite{#1})}.}
\newcommand{\ccreditnp}[1]{\textit{(credits: \textcite{#1})}}
\newcommand{\IEW}{Ion-exchange glass waveguide}
\newcommand{\iEW}{ion-exchange glass waveguide}
\newcommand{\PEW}{polymerization by evanescent waves}
\def\CC{{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.3ex}{\footnotesize\bf ++}}}
\def\CCT{{C\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.35ex}{\bf \footnotesize ++}}}

\newenvironment{changemargin}[2]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}%
      \setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}%
      \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
    }%
  \item[]}{\end{list}}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
%\linespread{1.2} change interline spacing

\let\oldvec\vec %keep the vector with arrow
%%--- end ---%%

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{empheq}

% for PSL cover
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{psl-cover}
%\usepackage[]{frontespizio} the frontespizio used for thesis in Florence


%bibliography informations
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none, url=false]{biblatex} %biblatex use
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

%Penality to avoid equations to break between lines:
\binoppenalty=10000
\relpenalty=10000

%package for chemical formulas
\usepackage{chemformula}

%for color line in table
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

%for colored box at the end of chapters
%\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{chrecap}{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,attach boxed title to top
        center={yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},
        colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,colbacktitle=red!80!black,
        title={Conclusions},fonttitle=\bfseries,
        boxed title style={size=small,colframe=red!50!black} ]
    }
    {
    \end{tcolorbox}
    }


% Finally, we use \endinput to indicate that LaTeX can stop reading this file. LaTeX will ignore anything after this line.
\endinput
```

Comment: `french` makes the colon active which can lead to problems. However, in a minimal setup nothing happens so please post a _complete_ example and explain what the "strange errors" are. It is usually the interaction with other packages which leads to problems. But if you are using french it would be better to just avoid `:` in labels.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added information on the preamble and on the first error. Unfortunately I already written more than 100 pages and would not like to change every label, if there is an alternative... 
Effectively, changing the label solve the problem. I also noted that the problem is not present with Lulatex, but then I have problems with libertine fonts...

Comment: Oh, you've got `commath` messing up too. That's the first thing I'd eliminate. Can you live without it?

Comment: I guess I could, but know eliminating it brings lots of errors. I need to change all the derivatives... Do you think the problem is in there?

Comment: `commath` is a rather buggy package. As a last resort you could try loading `commath` _before_ `babel`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved removing it. I replaced it with two commands, `\newcommand{\diff}{\partial\,}` and  `\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}`. I don't have that error anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to avoid problems with the four active characters in French (i.e. : ; ! ?) is to switch to a modern TeX engine, LuaTeX (or XeTeX). With these engines, there is no need for active characters, the required spaces before high punctuation are added another and safer way.

Switching is easy: see f.i. http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/doc/luatex/pdf2lua.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `commath` package, probably a bug. Removing it from preamble solved the problem. Is it also possible to avoid to use `:` in labels when using `french` language, as they can create problems.